Orleans Message Rejection Exception on Azure: Unable to Connect to Silo Endpoint
I’ve encountered an issue with an Orleans application running on Azure Virtual Machines. I have separate VMs for Dev and Prod environments. Locally, everything works fine, but when deployed to the Azure VMs, I get the following error in my application insights:
GetReviewTranscriptPromptRequest failed: {"AccessMechanism":2}
Exception:
Orleans.Runtime.OrleansMessageRejectionException: Exception while sending message: Orleans.Runtime.Messaging.ConnectionFailedException: Unable to connect to S10.0.0.254:20038:83628028, will retry after 981.0283ms

Setup:

Development Environment: Uses localhost clustering.
Production Environment: Uses Azure VMs with Azure Storage Clustering.

Here’s a snippet of my Orleans configuration:
if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    siloBuilder
        .UseLocalhostClustering(settings.OrleansSiloPort, settings.OrleansGatewayPort, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, settings.OrleansSiloPort))
        .Configure<ClusterOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ClusterId = settings.ClusterConfiguration.ClusterId;
            options.ServiceId = settings.ClusterConfiguration.ServiceId;
        })
        .SetupSiloStorage();
}
else
{
    var endpointAddress = IPAddress.Parse(context.Configuration["WEBSITE_PRIVATE_IP"]!);
    var strPorts = context.Configuration["WEBSITE_PRIVATE_PORTS"]!.Split(',');
    if (strPorts.Length < 2)
        throw new Exception("Insufficient private ports configured.");
    var (siloPort, gatewayPort) = (int.Parse(strPorts[0]), int.Parse(strPorts[1]));

    siloBuilder
        .ConfigureEndpoints(endpointAddress, siloPort, gatewayPort)
        .UseAzureStorageClustering(opt =>
        {
            opt.TableName = "OrleansSiloInstances";
            opt.TableServiceClient = new TableServiceClient(settings.TableStorageConfig.ConnectionString);
        })
        .Configure<ClusterOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ClusterId = settings.ClusterConfiguration.ClusterId;
            options.ServiceId = settings.ClusterConfiguration.ServiceId;
        })
        .SetupSiloStorage();
}

siloBuilder.UseDashboard(x => x.HostSelf = true);

Observations:

This issue only occurs on the server and never locally.
The connection to the specified IP (10.0.0.254) and port (20038) seems to fail intermittently.

Steps Taken:

Verified that the ports are open and accessible on the VM.
Ensured correct IP and port configurations in the Orleans setup.
Checked for any network issues or firewall restrictions between the VMs.

Questions:

What could be causing this connection failure specifically on the server, but not locally?
Are there any specific configurations or Azure VM settings I should look into to resolve this issue?

Any help or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated!
